# Why is ubiquityIdentityToken always nil?

Tags: ios, icloud, cloudkit

I am developing an iOS app that uses CloudKit. Apple's documentation says that I should use NSFileManager's ubiquityIdentityToken property to detect whether the service is available. But the property is always nil. How can I do to solve it? I am testing my app on an iPhone 5 simulator with iOS 8.2. And I have also logged into an iCloud account. I have also turned on iCloud Drive. (Someone says that turning on iCloud Drive may solve this problem, but this doesn't work for me.)

Do I need to call NSFileManager's method URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:? But Apple's documentation says that it is needed for document storage. It doesn't say that it is needed for CloudKit.

Answer (score 3):

The CKContainer [`accountStatusWithCompletionHandler`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKContainer_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CKContainer/accountStatusWithCompletionHandler:) method is how you should check whether the user is logged into iCloud or not (supported since iOS 8.0). The [CloudKit Quick Start shows an example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/CreatingaSchemabySavingRecords/CreatingaSchemabySavingRecords.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014987-CH3-SW8) of how to use it. [`fetchUserRecordIDWithCompletionHandler`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKContainer_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CKContainer/fetchUserRecordIDWithCompletionHandler:) is another option that might make sense for your app.

In iOS 9.0, you'll also have [`CKAccountChangeNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKContainer_class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/CKAccountChangedNotification), which will notify your app when the iCloud status on the device changes.